# how can i fix this pulse animation to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm setting up a new pulse animation inside my project

but this is not work how can i fix this and what is my problem ?

i want when i click(just one click without holding click long) on this circle get pulsing and after 2 second stop

```js
var  abox = document.getElementsByClassName("pulsediv")[0];
function pulsing(){

       abox.classList.toggle("pulse");
}
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}




.pulsediv{

  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: light;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5a99d4;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
}
.pulse {

   animation: pulse 2s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
  }
  70% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
    100% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
  }
```

```html
  <span class="pulsediv" onclick="pulsing">Hot</span>
```

Comment: You need to call the function: pulsing() instead of passing a reference to it inside onclick.

Comment: i did that ... i said if someone click on div the function pulsing perform can u explain more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix your animation, and call onClick function in Javascript, and it works.

```js
var abox = document.getElementsByClassName("pulsediv")[0];
// reset the transition by...
abox.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // -> removing the class
  abox.classList.remove("pulse");
  // -> and re-adding the class
  setTimeout(() => abox.classList.add("pulse"), 0);
}, false);
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.pulsediv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: light;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5a99d4;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(90, 153, 212, 0.5);
}

.pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9));
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(90, 153, 212, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(90, 153, 212, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulsediv">Hot</span>
```

Comment: i just have a question : why should i click twice to pulse? you know for the first time its work with on click and after clicked for the second time should click twice to work

Comment: Because I used toggle function in JavaScript.

Comment: You can use EventListener to stop previous animation (delete class), and start animation again

Comment: also have another question : how can i define this pulse for another input and class ? for example imagine i have 15 input and div i want all of them pulse when click on them should i use 15 javascript ?

Comment: @HosseiN you need Id's for that fields and one Javascript function that will be add class to that element

Comment: and also would you please edit your code convert it to what i want ? every time click on it work not to double click ....

Comment: i need this for my project and there is no one to help me also i should finish it up fast it means i dont have time to learn javascript please do these for me ... i have id for all of my field please update your answer

Comment: thanks for the fiddle that's exactly what i want  and for the second problem about id's what should i do ?

Comment: For the second problem you can use something like that
https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewKovalchuk/py2zjoq8/19/

Comment: i have 2 problem with your fixes after i add all of your solution to my project : 1- box-shadow change a little my text form input a dark shadow inside it i want to not show any of style before click in my desired form input because i want the pulse box shadow for click  2- for the input like type="color" or any input that perform an action i have problem because the input work just for first time and for second time i click on input (type="color") that doesn't open color box it means i have not problem with pulse i have problem with opening color box for second time when i click

Comment: it didn't allow me to perform second click on it for example when i click on checkbox input it didnt allow me to uncheck it ! for second time after i checked it  and also for input type color it didn't allow me to second another color and not open color box after select the color for first time

Comment: please help ... after long discussion... @Andrew Kovalchuk